# How to go about a non-nullable variable which is initialized later?

Tags: flutter, dart, null

```dart
class _BookAppState extends State<BookApp> {
  final List<Book> listBooks = [
    Book(bookName: 'The Alchemist', bookAuthor: 'Paulo Coelho'),
    Book(bookName: 'Harry Potter', bookAuthor: 'J. K. Rowling'),
    Book(bookName: 'Lord of the Rings', bookAuthor: 'R. R. Tolkein'),
  ];

  Book _selectedBook;

  void _handleBookTap(Book book) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedBook = book;
    });
  }
```

I have this variable `_selectedBook` which is initialized only when a book is tapped on. But it shows error in Dart analysis. It says that `_selectedBook` is a non-nullable variable.

I tried adding `late` but it throws an error. Should I use `Book?` or is there any other way to go about it?

Comment: What error does it throw on using `late`?

Comment: If using `late` is giving you an error, it means that you try to get `_selectedBook`'s value before it's been initialized.  You either will need to avoid doing that or will need to make `_selectedBook` nullable so you can directly check if it's been initialized or ont.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad `late` gives me `LateInitializationError: Field '_selectedBook@552409840' has not been initialized.`

Although I do initialize it in `_handleBookTap` function.

Comment: @Ishaan As James mentioned you're using it before it was initialized. Can you post the lines of code where you're seeing this error?

Comment: I solved it somehow! I initialized a global variable `Book _nullBook = Book(bookName: 'null', bookAuthor: 'null)` and then initialized `_selectedBook = _nullBook` and gave a few `if-else` conditions to check for `_nullBook`.

Comment: post an answer if you got it right

Comment: @Ishaan If you're doing `if-else` for checking nullability, its much better to make your field nullable `Book? _selectedBook`

Comment: Sure let me try that and post that as an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Book? _selectedBook;
```

it should work properly.